# Install Web Performance and Load Test Project Template into Visual Studio Professional 2012

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I want to do load testing inside Visual Studio Professional 2012. According to the tutorial here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms182551.aspx, under `File > Add > New Project > Installed Templates > Visual C# > Test` there should be a project template called `Web Performance and Load Test Project`.

But there is none in my tool. VS only presents Unit Test as here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/103580364/temp/pordiva000005.jpg

I searched inside online templates the keyword "performance" but there was no such a template again:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/103580364/temp/pordiva000006.jpg

How can I find and install that project template called `Web Performance and Load Test Project`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe you cannot do that. Web performance and load tests are only available within Visual Studio Ultimate edition. See http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare

In summary, there are five version of Visual Studio

- Express, the free version. Limited in functionality. Does not support extensions.
- Professional, has most of the development tools.
- Premium, adds Coded UI testing
- Ultimate, adds web performance and load testing.
- Test professional, has some test tools but no development tools.

Comment: @JasonFoglia NUnit addresses a different aspect of testing. Unit testing is quite different to performance testing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @AdrianHHH answer:
Running Visual Studio 2015 you will find it in the renamed Enterprise Edition.

VS2015 reduces to three versions:

- Visual Studio Community Free, fully-featured IDE for students,
  open-source and individual developers
- Visual Studio Professional Professional developer tools, services,
  and subscription benefits for small teams
- **Visual Studio Enterprise** End-to-end solution to meet demanding
  quality and scale needs of teams of all sizes

Basic info at [Visual Studio 2015 pricing](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/)

In detail at [Visual Studio 2015 Licensing White Paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350)