# Team explorer not loading Coded ui test in VSTS 2012 premium

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have VSTS 2012 premium in my system. I am using existing solution file. After opening existing project file I am not able to see load test in Team explorer in my VSTS 2012.Anything I have to update? But if I open new code dui test I am getting created test method in team explorer.
I updated VSTS 2012 update 3 also. Can you give me idea? How to load my existing order test file or test case in team explorer?

Comment: I am not getting any build error.

Comment: **Load tests** require the **Ultimate** edition of Visual Studio. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473652/install-web-performance-and-load-test-project-template-into-visual-studio-profes/17473984#17473984