# Web performance and load test project in VS 2012 Premium alternatives

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2012, load-testing, performance-testing

We are using VS2012 Premium edition, it misses "`Web Performance and Load Test project`" type, so I am wondering can someone suggest good alternative to do performance and load testing in VS premium edition? Is it possible to use Coded UI generated code to run it in parallel to simulate user interactions?

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI tests can be used within a Visual Studio Load Test. As Coded UI takes over the mouse, keyboard and screen of a computer you will need the same number of computers as the number of tests t be run at the same time. The computers may be real or virtual and the overhead of Coded UI is not great. So a computer that is powerful enough to comfortable run your application should be adequate.

The computers that run the Coded UI tests do not need Visual Studio installed. They need the Visual Studio "test agent" software that is easily downloaded from Microsoft. However you would need Visual Studio Ultimate or Team Foundation Server (TFS) to control the tests.

As far as I know, the only way to run load tests in Visual Studio is to use the Ultimate editions.

Here is a [summary of Visual Studio versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473652/install-web-performance-and-load-test-project-template-into-visual-studio-profes/17473984#17473984).