# Load testing in web service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I want to make load tests. I have Visual Studio 2010 Premium and Visual Studio 2013 Professional. But I can't make load tests by both.

The web service that I made is with C#. It gets called by an executable as a service reference and CRUD fields in the database.

Now I want to know how i can make load tests.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Web Performance and Load Test Project Template into Visual Studio Professional 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473652/install-web-performance-and-load-test-project-template-into-visual-studio-profes)

Comment: Visual Studio Web Performance tests and Load Tests are only available in the Ultimate edition. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473652/install-web-performance-and-load-test-project-template-into-visual-studio-profes/17473984#17473984

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout NLoad

https://github.com/nload/nload

NLoad is a simple class library that provides API for load testing your code.

For example, you can create a class that invokes your web service:

```
    public class MyTest : ITest
    {
      public void Initialize()
      {
        // Initialize your test, e.g., create a WCF client, load files, etc.
      }

      public void Execute()
      {
        // Send http request, invoke a WCF service or whatever you want to load test.
      }
    }
```

Then create, configure and run a load test:

```
var loadTest = NLoad.Test<MyTest>()
                      .WithNumberOfThreads(500)
                      .WithDurationOf(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                      .WithDeleyBetweenThreadStart(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
                      .OnHeartbeat((s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Throughput))
                    .Build();

var result = loadTest.Run();
```